# Question about inheritance in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I've been attempting to teach myself Ruby over the past while and I've been trying to get something like the following to work but I'm getting the following error...

`file.rb:44:in`func': undefined local variable or method `number' #<classname:0xb75d7840 @array=[]> (NameError)`

The code that's giving me this error is...

```
 class A
     def func
          file = File.new("file", "r") 
      file.each_line {|line| @numbers << line.chomp.to_i}
          @number = @array[0]
     end
 end

 class B < A
     def func
       super number
       puts number
     end
 end
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

edit// Just a clarification that I want number in class `B` to inherit the value of `@number` in class `A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like it's telling you, you're calling `super` and `puts` with an the argument `number` — but this `number` (whatever it's supposed to be) hasn't been defined anywhere. Define `number` to be something meaningful and the code will almost work. *Almost.*

The other mistake, which you'll discover after you've fixed that one, is that you're calling `super number`, which calls `A`'s `func` method with this mysterious `number` object as the argument — but `A#func` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Number has been defined in the inherited `load` function in class `A` I want it to inherit the value there. How do I do that?

Comment: No, it hasn't; it is a local variable in a function.  Do you know what the @ prefix does?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the '@' symbol to reference the instance level variable.

It is a really bad design anyway.  What if there are no lines in 'file'?  @numbers is never initialized.  You also wipe out @number completely on the next line with a variable (@array) that has never been defined.  Stop trying to fit everything in as few lines as possible and properly initialize your variables.

EDIT: Also, as Chuck noticed, you are passing an argument to a method that takes no arguments.

Comment: I think you mean `@numbers` is never initialized, not `@number`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that while you use the instance variable `@number`, calling `super number` (which isn't what you want, as this calls the superclass version of whatever method you're in, passing `number` as an argument) and `puts number` look up the *method* `number`.  If you really do want to just look up the instance variable, you just need `@number`; if you want to define such a method, put one of the following lines in your class:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :number # Define reader (number) and writer (number=)
  attr_reader   :number # Define only a reader
  attr_writer   :number # Define only a writer; won't be useful here
  # ...
end
```

And as [Ed Swangren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973488/question-about-inheritance-in-ruby/3973521#3973521) said, you ought to clean up `A`: initialize variables in `initialize`, make sure you define everything before using it, etc.

**Edit 1:** Corrected the description of the behavior of `super`.

Comment: you're wrong. `super` invokes the superclass method it is *not* a reference to the superclass. If you want to refer to the superclass then use `superclass` not `super`